# Unable to execute command error in netbeans

Tags: java

I am new to netbeans and java me. Pls help me with this problem

do i need to uninstall my netbeans and java me then reinstall?

I have installed java me sdk 3.4 but when irun my program is says that:

build-impl.xml:431: Unable to execute command (here is the error)
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

(this is the build-impl.xml:431)

---

package sampleapp;

```
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Alert;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Command;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.CommandListener;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Display;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Displayable;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Form;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.StringItem;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.TextField;
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;


public class Midlet extends MIDlet implements CommandListener{

    private Form form;
    private Display display;
    private StringItem stringItemHelloWorld;
    private TextField textFieldInput;
    private Command getInputCommand;
    private Command exitCommand;
    public Midlet() {
        form = new Form("My Form");
        stringItemHelloWorld = new StringItem(null,"Hello World!");
        textFieldInput = new TextField("Name", null, 10, TextField.ANY);
        getInputCommand = new Command(
                "Get Input",
                Command.OK,
                1
        );
        exitCommand = new Command(
        "Exit", Command.EXIT, 2);
    }

    public void startApp() {
        display = Display.getDisplay(this);
        stringItemHelloWorld = new StringItem(null, "Hello World");
        form.append(stringItemHelloWorld);
        form.append(textFieldInput);
        form.addCommand(getInputCommand);
        form.setCommandListener(this);
        display.setCurrent(form);
    }

    public void pauseApp() {
    }

    public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
    }

    public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable d) {
        if (c== getInputCommand){
        Alert alert = new Alert("Name");
        alert.setString(textFieldInput.getString());
                    display.setCurrent(alert);
                    stringItemHelloWorld.setText(
                    textFieldInput.getString()
                );
    }
        else if(c== exitCommand){
            destroyApp(false);
            notifyDestroyed();
        }
}
}
```

Comment: There 's a lot more to the error than just BUILD FAILED. look at the entire error message

Comment: <nb-preverify srcdir="${preverify.sources.dir}" destdir="${preverify.classes.dir}" classpath="${platform.bootclasspath}:${extra.classpath}" configuration="${platform.configuration}" platformhome="${platform.home}" platformtype="${platform.type}" commandline="${platform.preverifycommandline}"/>

that is the xml file

Comment: and thats the only error

Comment: any more information about the question, you should put in the question. Also: c == exitCommand is not the correct way to compare objects, use the equals method

Comment: this file is downloaded on my computer but it is working in our university
which means it is already tested

Comment: meaning what? most likely, you are missing a whole lot of configuration/dependencies/... on your machine, but by just saying BUILD FAILED, it's not really possible to find the correct answer quickly, except for with good-ole-luck

Comment: please check this https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=196116 they had same problem

Comment: @VishalKawade im afraid it is not the solution because the problem in that is unable to execute code 1

Comment: @Stultuske thats why im asking, it is the only error

Comment: @CarloBarrogo most likely, there is some logging somewhere. otherwise, see if you can add it.

Comment: @Stultuske okay thank you